# How do I run the main connect and app. run together?

Tags: python, loops, python-asyncio

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(AvatariaBot().connect("api.vk.avataria.tortugasocial.com", 8123))
    app.run()
```

Only the first connection is launched, it does not reach app.run

Comment: I have a feeling that asyncio uses an event loop, while you don't exit that, it doesn't move forward, try using threading for the other event loop

Answer (score 0):

```
asyncio.create_task(AvatariaBot())
```

Replace `asyncio.run` with `asyncio.create_task(AvatariaBot())`

Add `await asyncio.sleep(1)` into the end of your Bot.

Since asyncio using concurrent architecture, you need to release doing your task and let other tasks do their job

Main idea:

`asyncio.run` - running program(AvatarBot)

`app.run()` - unreachable because AvatarBot running forever

I'm using same solution in my Telegram bot, and that look like:

`dp.loop.create_task(main())`

main function - things to do concurrent like write new user into database

`executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)`

executor means I'm listening user input(user messages to bot)

My solution works, in basics:

Doing stuff in main()

Sleep 1 sec and let read user input, answer messages etc.

Doing stuff in main()

Hope that will work for you!

[Check this for more info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=asyncio%20create_task#asyncio.create_task)

Edit:

A little thing that I missed. Since you using asyncio, it's predictable that you're creating event loop before, that wasn't shown in your code.
So, add to your asyncio event loop task like that

```
loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(AvatariaBot())
```